# cssのfloatについて

Tags: html, css

画像と文字をfloatで横一列に並べたいです。

```
画像　　　　　　　　テキスト
　　　　　　　　　　テキスト
```

大きい画像のようなイメージです。

https://gyazo.com/482c3bfde93aa748a0db046f111fd086

HTMLは以下になります。

---

```
<body style="margin-top: 24px;">
    <div id="wrap">
    <div class="header"><img src="logo.png">CHEESE DEVELOPMENT</br>GROWTH CEESE</br>CHEESE PERSPECTIVE<br>CHEESE GENERATOR</div>
    <div class="gazou"><img src="bg-cheese.jpg"></div>
    <div class="gazou"><img src="catch.png"></div>
```

---

CSSは以下になります。

```
}
body{
  width:100%; /*ページ全体の幅は100%と指定する*/ 
  text-align:center;/*ページ全体を中央揃えにする*/
}
#wrap{ 
  width: 960px;    /*全体の幅を指定する*/  
  margin: 0 auto;    /*マージンの指定をする、ブラウザ対策*/
  /*全体を左揃えにする。*/
}   
header{
    float:right;
    text-align:right;
}
```

---

どなたかアドバイスを頂けますと幸いです。何卒よろしくお願いします。

Answer (score 1):

CSSでは、class属性への指定方法は「header」ではなくドットが前につき、「.header」となります。以下の書き方を試してください。

```
.header{
  float:right;
  text-align:right;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

対象となる画像タグに`float:left;`を記述します。
floatを使うには可能であればwidthとheightも指定した方が崩れにくくなります。
そして、floatした親ブロックには必ず`clear:both;`が必須になります。

`overflow:hidden;`は元々の意味ははみ出た部分の処理ですが、ブロック要素の空間位置特定を把握する機能が備わっています。私の書くCSSではほとんどが`overflow:hidden;`してあります。

```
.header img,
.gazou img {
  float:left;
  overflow: hidden;
  width: 300px; // 画像の横サイズ
  height: 200px; // 画像の縦サイズ
}
.wrap {
    overflow: hidden;
    clear: both;
}
```

Comment: [clear](https://developer.mozilla.org/ja/docs/Web/CSS/clear)は先行するfloatされた要素に対して回り込まないようにする指定ですから、親ブロックに指定しても意味がありません（いわゆるclearfixでは`::after`疑似要素と組み合わせます）。[サンプル](https://jsfiddle.net/44w43p5t/1/)

Comment: overflow:hidden;はClearFixの代替になります。

Comment: はい、overflowについては問題ないと思います。ただ、「floatした親ブロックには必ずclear:both;が必須になります」とも書かれていたので。